# Handle Custom File upload using <Lightning:input> in LWC

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

I want to use a custom file upload using  in LWC. But am not able to handle it in backend. I mean how to upload the file in .js file.

```
<lightning-input type="file"
                          label="Attachment"
                          accept=".txt, .docx"
                          onchange={handleFilesChange}
                          multiple>
 </lightning-input>
 <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">{fileName}</div>
```

In .js file:

```
handleFilesChange(event) {       

    this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;        
}
```

How to get a path in "event" to save this file? Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: I've been playing around with this for almost an hour, I followed the documentation to the best that I can as it says it needs to be wired up to an apex controller. My controller is getting an empty object with no properties. Your best bet for the time being might be the `lightning-file-upload` component instead.

Answer (score 1):

Selected [file](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/file/File/#Properties) object has only two properties **name** and **lastModifiedDate**. You can not get path information using **input with** **type="file**".

> The name of the file; on getting, this must return the name of the
>   file as a string. There are numerous file name variations on different
>   systems; this is merely the name of the file, **without path**
>   information. On getting, if user agents cannot make this information
>   available, they must return the empty string.

So you should use other alternative like lightning-file-upload for your requirement.